# Exports components from folder cause error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I updated react-router-dom from v5 to v6. After update I get following erorr:
**Object(...) is not a function**

After a few hours of debugging I found problem with exports. I have index.ts in ever folder where I export all components from folder. Example:

This is my ./media/index.tsx

```
import {Album} from './album';
import {AlbumGallery} from './album-gallery';
import {Videos} from './videos';
import {Image} from './image';
import {Video} from './video';
import {LockedMedia} from './locked-media';

export {
    Album,
    AlbumGallery,
    Videos,
    Image,
    Video,
    LockedMedia,
};
```

And this is my homepage.tsx

```
import React} from 'react';
import {Image} from 'app/media'; // This import not working
// import {Image} from 'app/media/image'; // This import is working, WTF?

export const Homepage = (): React.ReactNode => <div>
    <Image src="someUrl.png" />
</div>;
```

When I import Image component by this way **import {Image} from 'app/media'** I get error: Object(...) is not a function.

But when I import by this way **import {Image} from 'app/media/image** everythink is OK.

I don't understand what is the problem and it's very difficult refactor imports in whole project.

Solve somebody similar problem? Thanks in advance.

This is my tsconfig.json

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to export/import an `Image` component, or a `Media` component? Your issue description doesn't match the code at all. Please clarify the issue and check the code matches what you say is the problem. Please edit the post to include a [mcve] for all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using. This should include how you are exporting the components for import into other files.

Comment: I am trying export/import Image component. Sorry for mistake. I edit my post.

Comment: And can you share how all those components are individually exported?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't exporting anything called `Media` from `./media/index.tsx`.  I assume you ARE exporting it from `app/media/image` though.  So you can probably add something like the following (making assumptions about your file structure)

```
import { Image, Media } from './image';
...
export {
    Album,
    AlbumGallery,
    Videos,
    Image,
    Video,
    LockedMedia,
    Media,
};
```

and your original import should work.

Comment: Sorry, its only mistake in writing code in stackoverflow. I Edit my code import {Media} from 'app/media' to import {Image} from 'app/media'. I have no Media component.